# Display image using QImage without using pixmap in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a requirement to read pixel values from the picture displayed on the `GraphicScene` layout. How can I display image using `QImage` without using pixmap in Qt so that I am able to read the pixel values?

Comment: It's not clear what a problem you are facing.

Comment: If you want to show an image in a GUI you will have to use QPixmap anyway, why do not you want it ?, I think you have a total ignorance that is QPixmap and QImage.

Comment: @eyllanesc On Windows, a `QPixmap` is a thin wrapper around `QImage`, and so it is on mac, and on X11. Of course the image needs to be in a screen-compatible format, and only then are the two shared. So, `QImage`<->`QPixmap` conversions are fast as long as the image is of the correct format. And of course you don't need a `QPixmap` at all. You can draw a `QImage` (c.f. `QPainter::drawImage`).

Comment: @KubaOber 
What would be the advantage of using QImage instead of QPixmap?

Comment: @eyllanesc Well, for starters it will fulfill the requirement of the asker :) But generally, the pixmap and the image are cousins, and when drawing in raster backend, the `drawImage` and `drawPixmap` will perform identically as long as the image has a format similar enough to that of the target device (screen in case of widgets). An opaque `drawImage` with simple format conversions is essentially a vectorized `memcpy` that can twiddle bytes around. It is limited only by the memory bandwidth.

Comment: @KubaOber Exactly, that's what I know, QGraphicsPixmapItem already exists, why the need to create another ?, unless you have some specific need.

Comment: Even if there is a specific need, it's probably an xy problem. `QImage` isn't meant for on-screen display, which is why it's intentionally easy to convert to a `QPixmap`.

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms, a `QPixmap` is a thin wrapper around a `QImage`. The conversions between the two are cheap - especially the pixmap-to-image conversion. Thus, you can use the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` and use `item->pixmap().toImage()` without much worry. To confirm that `QPixmap` is indeed a wrapper, the following check will do:

```
bool isPixmapThin(const QPixmap &pix) {
  auto const a = pix.toImage();
  auto const b = pix.toImage();
  return a.bits() == b.bits();
}
```

In all cases, ensure that the image you take from the pixmap won't detach, i.e. always make it `const` (as in the code example above).